# Wireshark not detecting TLS connection

Tags: python, sockets, ssl, wireshark

I want to make a TLS communication, but when I want to check it with WireShark, it said that it is a normal TCP connection that does not use TLS.  It shouldn't be, due to the certificate.

client:

```py
import socket
import ssl

hostname = 'localhost'
# PROTOCOL_TLS_CLIENT requires valid cert chain and hostname
context = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLS_CLIENT)
context.load_verify_locations('certificates/ca.pem')

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

ssock = context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=hostname)
ssock.connect((hostname, 8080))

print(ssock.version())
ssock.send("TLSnotWorking".encode("UTF-8"))

ssock.close()
```

server:

```py
import ssl
import socket

context = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLS_SERVER)
context.load_cert_chain('certificates/server.pem', 'certificates/server.key')

with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM, 0) as sock:
    sock.bind(('127.0.0.1', 8080))
    sock.listen(5)
    with context.wrap_socket(sock, server_side=True) as ssock:
        try:
            while True:
                conn, addr = ssock.accept()
                
                try:
                    while True:
                        msg = conn.recv(4096)
                        if not len(msg):
                            conn.close()
                            break

                        print(msg.decode("UTF-8"))

                except Exception as e:
                    print(e)
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
                conn.close()
                ssock.shutdown(socket.SHUT_RDWR)
                ssock.close()
```

Comment: Looks fine to me.  A TLS handshake should be performed automatically in `ssock.connect()` and `ssock.accept()` since `wrap_socket()` is set to `do_handshake_on_connect=True` by default. Are you *sure* you are looking at the correct TCP connection in Wireshark? [Capturing `localhost` traffic is not enabled by default](https://gitlab.com/wireshark/wireshark/-/wikis/CaptureSetup/Loopback).

Comment: *" ... it said that it is a normal TCP connection that does not use TLS "* - Wireshark does not say something like *"does not use TLS"*. Maybe you did not actually make it interpret the traffic as TLS on this non-standard port so you only see TCP even if it is TLS (on top of TCP).

Comment: https://osqa-ask.wireshark.org/questions/51310/does-wireshark-recognize-non-standard-https-ports

Comment: Hi I'm new to wireshark, just wondering how I can use it to verify the TLS version for the connection to an Aurora RDS database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

wireshark can tell if it is TLS but I just used a wrong port, for example "8443" at the port you can see if there is TLS communication